# Is $\sqrt2+\pi$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/why-is-it-hard-to-prove-whether-pie-is-an-irrational-number), as a layman I wonder if the same goes for $\sqrt2+\pi$?
How about $\pi+\log2$?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197927/is-the-sum-of-an-algebraic-and-transcendental-complex-number-transcendental) may be of interest.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you, so the first one is obvious. Can I ask you further if $\log 2$ is algebraic?

Comment: I don't know ($\ln 2$ is transcendental).

Comment: Algebraic numbers are closed under addition and multiplication (in fact, they form a field). That is, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of some polynomial then so are $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$. This is what is going on in Don Antonio's answer.

Clearly $\sqrt2$ is algebraic (root of $x^2-2$), as is every rational number ($a/b$ is a root of $bx-a$). So if $\sqrt2+\pi=r$ then $\pi=r-\sqrt2$ is algebraic, as by closure of addition.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose the sum is rational, say $\;r\;$,  but then

$$r=\sqrt2+\pi\implies r^2-2r\pi+\pi^2=2\implies \pi\;\;\text{is a root of the polynomial}$$

$$p(x)=x^2-2rx+r^2-2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;,\;\;\text{which of course is absurd}$$

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate about $\pi+\log 2$?

Comment: With $\log 2$, it pretty well may be an open problem, and an immensely hard one at that.